# Have begun or began in this case

Tags: past-tense

My original vinyls lp's began OR have begun  to scratch,I had played'them so many times.

I think the first one is better but have begun can fit because it is recent .
Is it possible to write
My original lp's begin  to scratch  because I've played
them so many times.

Comment: If you are talking about present perfect. I believe it would be "have/has+past participle". So, it's have begun. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: My LPs began to scratch a long time ago. My LPs have begun to scratch recently. My LPs are beginning to scratch now.

Comment: Why not begin ?we can use the progressive in this case because a beginning is not really a process